# I've accidentally spilled water on my touchpad some days ago

Tags: windows

1. It started getting hanged since then
2. I can't understand what to do now
3. I'm in deep stress as this is my new and first laptop
4. My laptop is dell inspiron 15 3000
5. Please help me

Comment: Get a new Keyboard / Touchpad from Dell. Not covered under warranty.

Comment: Or use an external mouse (and keyboard?) if possible.

Comment: Leaving it to dry & hoping it will just magically get better isn't really the way to do it. Take it to a repair shop before it gets a lot worse - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392674/what-procedure-should-be-followed-post-spilling-fluids-onto-a-macbook-keyboard/392675#392675 [it doesn't matter that this is for a Mac, the principal is the same].